# elisp: output colorful message in echo area

Tags: emacs, echo, message, spacemacs

the following is output of my shell command

```
Result [31mERROR[0m Invalid Transition "Backlog" from "In Progress", Available: Ready for Code Review, Stop Development
```

I'm trying to output it in the echo area this way:

```
(setq result (shell-command-to-string (
            concat "j transition \"" state "\" " jira-ticket " --noedit")))
  (message "Result %s" result))
```

but it doesn't print the red-color "ERROR",

#### is it possible in emacs?

and if not possible - how to strip such letters automatically?

System Info :computer:

- OS: gnu/linux
- Emacs: 26.1
- Spacemacs: 0.200.13
- Spacemacs branch: master (rev. c7a103a7)
- Graphic display: t
- Distribution: spacemacs
- Editing style: emacs
- Completion: helm
- Layers:
  `elisp
  (gnus php yaml themes-megapack html javascript helm
    (auto-completion :variables auto-completion-enable-snippets-in-popup t)
    emacs-lisp
    (git :variables git-magit-status-fullscreen t magit-save-repository-buffers 'dontask magit-refs-show-commit-count 'all magit-revision-show-gravatars nil)
    markdown org
    (shell :variables shell-default-height 30 shell-default-term-shell "/usr/bin/zsh" shell-default-position 'bottom)
    (syntax-checking :variables flycheck-select-checker 'javascript-eslint)
    (version-control :variables version-control-diff-tool 'diff-hl version-control-global-margin t)
    evil-commentary chrome python django dmitry)`
- System configuration features: `XPM JPEG TIFF GIF PNG RSVG IMAGEMAGICK SOUND DBUS GSETTINGS NOTIFY ACL LIBSELINUX GNUTLS LIBXML2 FREETYPE M17N_FLT LIBOTF XFT ZLIB TOOLKIT_SCROLL_BARS GTK3 X11 MODULES THREADS XWIDGETS LCMS2`

Comment: I don't have a solution, but here is an example of how I print colorful messages in the GUI version of Emacs:  `(message (concat (propertize "NEXT" 'face '(:foreground "ForestGreen")) ":  C-u ESC . | " (propertize "PREVIOUS" 'face '(:foreground "firebrick")) ":  C-u - ESC ."))`  The color shows up in the echo area, but not the `*Messages*` buffer, which contains just plain text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

n.b. I'm assuming you *are* getting proper ansi escape codes, and the escape characters were just lost in the process of posting the question.

---

Here's a solution derived from the `alter-text-property` code.

```el
(defun copy-font-lock-face-to-face (from to &optional object)
  "Programmatically copy `font-lock-face' text-properties as `face' properties.

Optional third argument OBJECT specifies the string or buffer to operate on."
  ;; Derived from `alter-text-property'.
  (let ((begin from)
        end val)
    (while (setq val (get-text-property begin 'font-lock-face object)
                 end (text-property-not-all begin to 'font-lock-face val object))
      (put-text-property begin end 'face val object)
      (setq begin end))
    (if (< begin to)
        (put-text-property begin to 'face val object))))

(defun message-with-ansi-color (format-string &rest args)
  "A variant of `message' which supports ansi color escape codes."
  (require 'ansi-color)
  (let* ((text (ansi-color-apply (apply #'format format-string args))))
    (copy-font-lock-face-to-face 0 (length text) text)
    (message "%s" text)))

(message-with-ansi-color "%s" "Result \e[31mERROR\e[0m Invalid Transition")
```

Original answer follows...

---

I had expected `ansi-color-apply` to do the trick:

```el
(require 'ansi-color)
(message "%s" (ansi-color-apply "Result \e[31mERROR\e[0m Invalid Transition \"Backlog\" from \"In Progress\", Available: Ready for Code Review, Stop Development"))
```

But it looks like `message` handles<sup>1</sup> `face` text properties, but not `font-lock-face` text properties, and `ansi-color-apply` produces the latter (if you modify the definition of that function to change `font-lock-face` to `face` then you will get the message in colour).

If you wanted to go to the trouble, you could manipulate the resulting string to convert those text properties, which from my reading should be a completely safe thing to do:

> ‘font-lock-face’
>       This property specifies a value for the ‘face’ property that Font Lock mode should apply to the underlying text.

I assume there's something in the font-lock code which could do that for you, but I don't know what that is -- hopefully someone more familiar can fill in that gap.

To *strip* the escape codes from the string, you can use `ansi-color-filter-apply` instead of `ansi-color-apply`.

---

<sup>1</sup> for echo area output only; text properties are not applied in the `*Messages*` buffer, as lawlist has pointed out.